# How to get AWS RDS CPU and memory metric using script other then cloudwatch

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, cron, rds

I am hosting Linux server and RDS Posgresql server in Amazon Web Services. I would like to get AWS RDS CPU Utilization, Memory usage  Metric using linux script. other than cloudwatch. Is there any way to do it..? I don't want to go with any third party software. i need to write cron job in linux.

Comment: You will not get access at OS level on RDS since it is "Managed" relational database service .
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install aws cli if not already installed, then use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html

Example:

`aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace 'AWS/RDS' --metric-name 'CPUUtilization' --start-time '2017-05-25T12:00:00Z' --end-time '2017-05-25T12:30:00Z' --period 60 --statistics 'Maximum'`

Comment: Instruction provided to get Ec2 metrics. Can i follow same way to get RDS metrics..?

Comment: I edited the post with sample command. CLI is well documented, so I have no idea where the question came from. Just read the exact page I linked to, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Can we get stats from os process list using any cli command? E.g., ```RES``` memory of a process from the list.